# global_plan goes through the wall

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using navigation stack with following parameters:

**(costmap_common_params.yaml)**

> global_frame: /map
>
> robot_base_frame: base_footprint
>
> update_frequency: 0.5
>
> publish_frequency: 0.5
>
> obstacle_range: 2.5
>
> raytrace_range: 3.0
>
> min_obstacle_height: 0.6
>
> inflation_radius: 1.5
>
> observation_sources: scan
>
> scan: {sensor_frame: laser_scan_link,
> data_type: LaserScan, topic:
> stereo/laser_scan, marking: true,
> clearing: true}

**(eband_planner_params.yaml)**

> EBandPlannerROS:

> ## TRAJECTORY CONTROL

> differential_drive: true

> ## velocity limits

> max_vel_lin: 0.4

> max_vel_th: 0.2

> min_vel_lin: 0.08

> min_in_place_vel_th: 0.05

> ## goal tolerance

> xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2

> yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.2

**(global_costmap_params.yaml)**

> global_costmap:

> robot_base_frame: base_footprint

> update_frequency: 0.5

> publish_frequency: 0.5

> static_map: true

> transform_tolerance: 0.5

> footprint_padding: 0.05

**(local_costmap_params.yaml)**

> local_costmap:

> global_frame: /map

> robot_base_frame: base_footprint

> update_frequency: 0.5

> publish_frequency: 0.5

> static_map: true

> rolling_window: true

> width: 5.0

> height: 5.0

> resolution: 0.05

> transform_tolerance: 0.5

> footprint_padding: 0.0

**(move_base_params.yaml)**

> footprint: [[0.375, 0.375], [0.375, 0.0], [0.4125, 0.0], [0.4125, -0.0375], [0.375, -0.0375], [0.375, -0.375], [-0.075, -0.375], [-0.075, -0.4875], [-0.375, -0.4875], [-0.375, 0.4875], [-0.075, 0.4875], [-0.075, 0.375]]

The controller_frequency is set to 1.0.
The problem is that the global plan computed goes through the wall. The plan of NavfnROS is fine. The bad one in the image is the global plan of EBandPlannerROS (robot tries to follow this one).
As seen by the below image, Laser scan is well defined. I don't understand why this path is computed. Can anyone help me on this issue please?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221380/global_plan-goes-through-the-wall/) by [aba92](https://answers.ros.org/users/21911/aba92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just left eband planner. I am using the standard one, base_local_planner, and everything is ok! Thank you

---

Originally posted by [aba92](https://answers.ros.org/users/21911/aba92/) with karma: 29 on 2015-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0